# Replacing nulls from database in Model (EF)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The database I am working with (I have no control over this) has nulls in a column that seems to be messing up my code. I want to handle this in the Model portion of my project as it seems to be the appropriate place. Creating a customer getter sounds like a good idea to me.

**Class**

```
public string _DesignLink { get; set; } 
public virtual string DesignLink {
    get { return _DesignLink ?? ""; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
...
modelBuilder.Entity<ToolPlan>().Property(t => t._DesignLink).HasColumnName("DesignLink");
...
}
```

The logic works in my mind. Create a virtual property in order to make the getter work, then remap the property to the real column. The error given to me is:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmProperty: Name: The specified name is not allowed: '_DesignLink'.
```

This error occure on access the database for the first time. How can I make all null values in this column show up at empty spaces in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sort of going about this the hard way. A custom getter is not a bad plan, but you just need the property itself:

```
private string designLink;
public string DesignLink
{
    get { return designLink ?? string.Empty; }
    set { designLink = value; }
}
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: Except saving this entity will no longer result in a `null` value in the DB, which may be required for proper functionality elsewhere.  I like the wrapped accessor much better as it preserves original functionality.

Comment: If the OP needs to maintain the database null value, he can simply add that property to a view model instead of the model itself.

Comment: I guess I was overthinking the issue, as usual. In regards to the discussion above, I am only reading from this table, so the point made above is moot in my case. Good point though

Answer (score 0):

You just need a bit of decoration with `NotMapppedAttribute` and `ColumnAttribute`:

```
[Column("DesignLink")] // want this property to map to DB column
public string _DesignLink { get; set; } 

public string DesignLink {
    get { return _DesignLink ?? ""; }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `NotMapped` attribute if the property is read only, but then we probably need a setter here - so I'd suggest adding `set { _DesignLink = value == "" ? null : value; }`

Comment: ha good point, `NotMapped` not needed, but the `Column` attribute solves the problem